# vb.net add days to a date

Tags: vb.net, datetime

```
Dim DespatchDate As DateTime
Dim ReceiptDate As DateTime 

DespatchDate = #3/7/2017 12:00:00 AM#  'I am in the UK so this is 3rd July 2017

ReceiptDate = DespatchDate.AddDays(60)   'Returns #5/6/2017 12:00:00 AM#
```

I would expect "1/9/2017" the 1st September 2017

I also tried

```
ReceiptDate = DateAdd("d", 10, DespatchDate)  which returned #3/17/2017 12:00:00 AM#
```

I must be doing something wrong but what?

Comment: Your problem is with the  [date literal](msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711653(v=vs.71).‌​aspx). Please read [Ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 4):

The date literal in VB uses the US format regardless of where you are. Your code:

```
DespatchDate = #3/7/2017 12:00:00 AM#  'I am in the UK so this is 3rd July 2017
```

is creating the date March 7 2017. Read more on date literals or use the constructor on the date class that makes it more apparent what you are doing.

**Update**
In order to be sure what the date is and to avoid ambiguity, you can define it this way:

```
DespatchDate = New Date(2017, 7, 3)   ' Without the time of day, 12AM is implied
DespatchDate = New Date(2017, 7, 3, 12, 34, 56) ' July 3 2017 12:34:56 PM
```

The good thing with this is you can see from intellisense while typing the code what each number means. And if someone else had written the code, you can invoke intellisense to see what each argument means. As you can see from what I highlighted in my screenshot, the time is in 24 hour format.

[image: Screenshot of what you will see from intellisense]

Comment: IMO using the constructor is the least ambiguous: e.g. `New Date(2017, 7, 3)`

Comment: In VS2015, date literals can use yyyy-MM-dd, e.g. `Dim d = #2017-06-26 8:17PM#`. Ref: [Date Data Type (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/date-data-type).

Comment: > The reason for this restriction is that the meaning of your code should never change depending on the locale in which your application is running. 

@AndrewMorton That line pretty much sums it up. so as not to have different meanings, it will evaluate the literal with month before day.

Comment: @Fabulous I agree with SSS that using a date constructor is the simple way to get unambiguity. While you have answered the direct question, a little more information in your answer could make it worthy of an upvote.

Comment: @AndrewMorton thanks for the feedback. I have updated my answer to add more info on how to use the date constructor.